# Android Service and SQLite Access Data Integrity

Tags: android, sqlite, service

I start a simple android service with startService. The service creates a thread and in this thread some sqlite database operations take place (updates and inserts).

Am I completely safe by enclosing all the operations in a single transaction in the case of OS killing my service while my code is still executing and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I completely safe by enclosing all the operations in a single transaction in the case of OS killing my service while my code is still executing and why?

If your app's transaction logic itself is correct then yes, you can assume the database will be in a consistent state once the app is restarted. ACID properties of transactions guarantee that the transactions are applied in full or not at all. In practice, if your app is killed in a middle of transaction, none of the operations in that transaction are applied.

Further reading to learn how transactions work on the underlying OS level: http://sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html

Comment: I'm leaning towards your answer. What happens if the service is killed while executing endTransaction()? I want to believe that there is a single point in time before which the transaction is not considered finished and after which it is considered finished.

Answer (score 0):

The Android OS will attempt to keep the service running for as long as the service is up and running or there are clients bound to this service. If your code in the service is executing under within the onCreate(), onStartCommand() or onDestroy(), the service will be considered a foreground process and will not be killed. But it can kill it off if under extreme low memory conditions.

So to answer your question, having all your operations in a single transaction is no guarantee that the Android OS will wait to wrap up the transaction before killing it. The factors that it uses to determine whether a service is killed or not does not depend on DB transactions.

Comment: I dont care if the transaction will succeed or not I care about leaving the database in a non consistent state or not.

Comment: Like the user above stated, then the database will not be left in a non consistent state as none of the operations within the transaction would go through and you would basically be left with an untouched database.